# Apache httpd version for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4

Tags: linux

Can anyone suggest the appropriate version for Apache httpd for RHEL 4 ? I know its not supported by RHEL anymore but the application demands this version. So, any leads will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to stick with RHEL 4 or any of its downstream rebuilds like CentOS 4, you have two choices:

1. Use the version of the `httpd` package that came with the OS, 2.0.52. Despite the name, this is Apache.
2. Build whatever you'd prefer to use from source. Assuming you build a current version and keep it up to date, this is better for security, but then the resulting combination can't really be said to be "RHEL 4" any more, which may bother the application that demands RHEL 4.